# Telnet SmarterMail: 550 This is a submission only port. You must authenticate before sending mail

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2019, telnet

I have a "newer" server running Windows Server 2019 and I installed Smartermail FREE Edition so I could send mail via PHP/CDONTs from contact forms to my email address.

I tried matching the settings on an older Server with an older Smartermail but I can't get it to work.

When I try "telnet 127.0.0.1 587" in command prompt, then EHLO then mail from: etc... I get the error

**550 This is a submission only port. You must authenticate before sending mail**

I also get the error **SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.** in phpMail, but I suspect I need to get the 550 submission only port error fixed first.

I have tried searching Google and server fault and can't find a solution.

I'm not sure what logs that I need to provide, nor know where to find them.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP/MSA on port 587 is for the Mail Submission Agent role only. Client authentication is required at all times. If you don't want to authenticate, use the standard SMTP port 25.

Normally, the server will need some other way of trusting you when sending from a local email address, e.g. you'd need to connect from a private IP address, to  an internal-only interface, to a private-only IP address or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I feel like I'm so close but so far. I switched to using port 25 when sending mail and it says that the user isn't found. However, it is found. So now I  have to figure out how to get Smartermail to send and ignore the Smartermail user base when validating users.

Comment: You're not providing sufficient information for anyone to comment that.

Comment: I understand. I'm just not sure what information that I need to provide.

Comment: Thought about including your Smartermail config? Which is where you define trusted endpoints?

Comment: there is just a ton of configuration in Smartermail. I wasn't sure what was relevant.